# No internet connection in Windows Phone 8 Emulator on WiFi

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8

I am having bit of a peculiar problem. Windows Phone 8 Emulator is unable to connect to internet when my host laptop is connected to WiFi. However, internet freely works when I connect the laptop using LAN to the same router. I checked and compared the configuration in both the cases. It is exactly the same! Here are screenshots of both the cases.

On WiFi adapters look like this and there's not internet on the emulator:
[image]

On wired connection, adapters look like this and internet happily works:[image]

I'm totally confused about this. Everything worked on Windows 8. After upgrading to Windows 8.1 problems started.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to WiFi, verify the IPv4 settings in vEthernet(Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch);

- In IPv4 setting -> General Tab -> select "Obtain an IP address automatically"

-OR-

- Try adding IP address manually in the IPv4 settings.
- also add the Preferred DNS Servers and Alternate DNS server

I hope this helps.